# Using same pictures twice in one node (media module)

Tags: nodes, media

I've been using the EPSA crop module for a while now without any complaints. But I've run into a small problem, which I can't fix. I use the media module in combination with the EPSA crop module. When I add a picture twice in one node then only one cutout will be saved and all the same pictures will be cut the same way. So a cutout isn't unique. Does someone have an idea?

Using Media 7.x-2.0-beta1 and EPSA crop 7.x-2.3.

Answer (score 1):

No solution right now, because all the cropping modules stores their information using fid, without entity id or something else which can give information where it will be used. As a workaround on this problem, I altered some crop forms and created a new image per each crop.

Comment: So there isn't actually and advantage when you use the media module in combination with a crop module? Reusing images isn't possible? Thanks!

Comment: Based on my experience, I think it's no possible to reuse images. But you can alter some forms ;) All the new crop will override previous. Maybe if I have a time, I will try to create some contrib module for it.